# datagrid in visual basic 6.0 is not updating

Tags: windows, datagrid, vb6, coding-style

I'm doing a tuition centre database and registration system using vb 6.0, I had created two form, which form 1 is for secretary to type in the data of the student that registered, and the second form is the database, which I used the Adodc method and use datagrid to view. My problem is when the first time I insert the data, and click save in form 1, I go to form 2, the first data is in the datagrid, but when i going back to form 1 and insert a new data and save, then I go to form 2, the second data is not there, only the first data is there. The second data will only appear after I exit the whole system and turn on back the system again. How can I make my datagrid updating the data every time I save? I look for the answer in google, the answer given by the provider normally is from vb.NET, but mine is vb 6.0.

Comment: is your datagrid bound to a recordset or it is unbound? i.e. you are manually populating the datagrid?

Comment: its bound to my recordset, because everytime I enter and click "save" button, the data will be there, its just won't show up until I exit and executed again.

Comment: requery the recordset everytime it changes.

Comment: please post some code. especially the code in which you send the data, and the code of form_load and form_activate or any other form_... events of form2

Comment: is form2 still visible when you go back to form1? if not, then you can unload form2 which might probably have the same effect as exiting the whole system

Answer (score 0):

try to refresh the datagrid. "datagrid.refresh" or refresh the entire database by updating code.  click the link below. 
http://www.angelfire.com/cantina/flashando/ch02/ch02.htm